# .htaccess authentication in android

Tags: android, apache, .htaccess

I'm creating an android app that interacts with a MySql database through a PHP page.

So I need to do an authentication on the page and I used the .htaccess apache auth (you can see the login form here http://www.imaginsystems.it/uni/)

The problem is that I couldn't find anywhere the code to automate this login. Does someone have this code??

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered to write this code yourself? I have heard that it was common in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're wanting to send the username & password with the request from your App to your PHP script?

I believe you can use this format for sending that kind of login information with the URL:

`http://username:password@www.imaginsystems.it/uni/`